# One floated div with AUTO, then another div that fill the rest

Tags: html, css

I need to put two divs inside another. Divs which are inside are floated, one has a "width: auto;" and the another one must fill the rest.

I've seen many examples, but everything works with at least one fixed width and I'm not working with fixed widths.

The structure is as follows:

```
<div id="bigboss">
 <div id="child1"></div>
 <div id="child2"></div>
</div>
```

"bigboss" has a "width: 100%", "child1" has "width: auto;" I need that Child 2 fill the rest.

[image]

Comment: do you absolutely need the child 2 div to be floated? Not floating it would work http://jsfiddle.net/94KUZ/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS has no function 'fill the rest'. You will probably need javascript for this.

you could use jQuery to do the following:

```
$(document).load(function(){
    $("#child2").css({
        "width": $("#bigboss").width() - $("#child1").width() + "px"
    });
});
```

as seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/YUjJ8/

Comment: If you have images or any other external content in the child `div` I would use `.load()` instead of `.ready()` to wait for them to load as well, because they could affect the element size. But beware that this also means that `load()` is executed much later than `ready()`, so the user may see strange layout changes when all is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

I think that there is no easy way to do this in CSS2. But you can use Flexbox layout of CSS3.

Here is an example (http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gifeu)

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;

  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper > * {
  padding: 10px;
}


.main {
  text-align: left;
  background: deepskyblue;
  flex: 1 100%;
}

.aside {
  background: gold;
  flex: 1 auto;
}
```

And here is a tutorial on Flexbox: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

If you don't care about IE9, Flexbox support is good: http://caniuse.com/#search=flex

Answer (score 0):

There's no (easy) way to do this with CSS2, but it's very simple with [CSS3 Flexbox](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/).

Comment: if it wasn't for internet explorer. Better answer, but unfortunately still needs fallback.